# Jquery accordion code

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I found that code on the internet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#accordian h3").click(function(){
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
    if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
    {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
})
 })
```

I want to know what this part of the code is doing:

```
if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
    {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
})
})
```

Comment: You don't need this all when you are using Jquery Accordion. Just `$( "#accordion" ).accordion();` is enough.
If you want to know the explanation for above code, You might need to put HTML code also to explain about `ul` Because in normal Jquery accordion, we don't need `ul`

Comment: I found it here http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/vertical-accordion-menu-using-jquery-css3

Comment: It is not JQuery Accordion. It is making Accordion using CSS and JQeury. This is Jquery accordion http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It checks if the next element is visible, if it's not, it calls the next element and executes a slideDown() command.

$(this) in the context of the code refers to the dom elements retrieved using '#accordian h3' selector